# Create Gitlab issues based on the Elasticsearch SIEM alerts

Tags: elasticsearch, gitlab

I'm trying to integrate Elastic SIEM alerts to Gitlab issues. I would need to create issues in Gitlab based on alerts from Elasticsearch.

I could see there is no direct connector available in Elastic.

Appreciate guidance on implementing the above usecase.

Thanks in Advance.

I have tried creating connector in Elastic but there is support for Gitlab.